# Global and Local variables in python: Creating nine random numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to run my program below, that is supposed to generate 9 random numbers and output them, when the function getRandom() is called. However when I try to run I receive an error local variable 'num' referenced before assignment.

```
Import random as rd


myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def getRandom():
    for x in range(9):
        g = rd.choice(myList)
        num = num + g
    return num

print(getRandom())
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: because you never initialise num? `num = num + g`, where is the first `num` on the right-hand side to start with?

Comment: Also, you are spamming tags as the only related tag would be `python`

Comment: `num = num + g` requires that `num` already exist, which it does not.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `num = num + g`, what should happen the first time? What should `g` get added to?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable first.

```
import random as rd

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def getRandom():
    num = [] # Declare the num variable.
    for x in range(9):
        g = rd.choice(myList)
        num.append(g)
    return num
    
print(getRandom())
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to make a list of values, rather than summing them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I updated the function to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing operation on a variable which is not defined earlier.
if you want list as output do something like this.

```
import random as rd

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def getRandom():
    num=[]
    for x in range(9):
        g = rd.choice(myList)
        num.append(g)
    return num

print(getRandom())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a few things wrong here (not going to nitpick on the 'i' in "import" being capitalized")

1. The line `num = num + g` is obviously wrong. You're trying to add `g` to something that does not exist yet. If you were to use this method of declaring num, you'd first have to have to declare the `num` variable (`num = 0`, for example) before adding to it.
2. Even if you did not have this error, your program would not do what you want it to do. As you said in your question, you want to generate 9 random numbers and output all of them, for example an output could be the list: `[1, 9, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 0, 1]`. However, currently, you're generating 9 `num` values within the function - and then only returning the last one. For example, if my expected output was the list I listed for example earlier, you'd only output `1`.

Here's an example of a program that would work:

```
import random as rd
from typing import List

def getRandom() -> List[int]:
    nums = []
    for x in range(9):
        num = rd.randint(0, 9)
        nums.append(num)
    return nums

print(getRandom())
```

Note: I've used rd.randint() above instead of your method, which is a much simpler way of generating random integers within a certain range.